# Django translate the user permissions

Tags: django, django-admin

Hello is it possible to translate the user permissions

This is in bulgarian but there is still `can add`/`can change`

[image: this is in admin panel now it is in bulgarian]
can anyone help please

Comment: You can create custom permissions in you language or rename the current permissions you already have in place.

Comment: @WayBehind awesome I'll try that tomorrow

Comment: BTW I usually do this kind of work directly through my MySQL console.